# Split a file based upon the line character length

Tags: split

I have a file which contain below lines. The starting word of each line is call and the end line is semicolon. I need to find the character size of each line and then move it to a file. If the character size is more than 255 then I need to push that line to a next file and I need to keep on doing this for every 255 characters in a file but I cant break this line because its a index rebuild script.

Input:

```
call sp_rebuildindex('dbo.xxx','column [clean_timezone_string]');
call sp_rebuildindex('dbo.vvvv','column [pkey_best_no_address_2]');
call sp_rebuildindex('dbo.zzzz','column [clean_address_type_code]');
call sp_rebuildindex('dbo.ttttt','column [clean_city_abbreviation]');
```

Comment: please show what you have tried so far.  And what language are you using to solve this problem.

Comment: None of the lines shown are longer than 255 characters. Please show an accurate example and also what you have attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: I think OP intends to concat lines into longer lines, with each line no longer than 255, if would be longer than 255 then start a new line.